# Job scheduler design with fault tolerance and high volume of execution

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, quartz-scheduler, vert.x

I have a Java program which continuously checks for scheduled job and executes it.

The number of scheduled job at a time could be in **around 1000**.

Like at time `21:30`, 1000 different jobs are scheduled and by next `21:31` another 700 different jobs.

In the quad-core processor, 4 threads can run the job in parallel.

Mostly my program **is not able to pick and complete all jobs** and by the time next set of jobs arrives into the system. 
Because of this number of **pending jobs increases** and **keep getting added**.

In my design, I  am keeping pending jobs in a database table and pick up next time immediately any thread is available.

Inside my jobs, it does mostly IO intensive work. Can I keep more number of threads than CPU core as its `IO intensive` ?

I am keeping job status in DB table like below,

```
---------------------------------------------
JOB   | TIME  | STATUS
--------------------------------------------
J1    | 21:21 | Waiting
J2    | 21:21 | Waiting
J3    | 21:21 | Running
J4    | 21:21 | Running
J5    | 21:22 | Waiting
```

I have process jobs in sequence, Is my design `fault tolerant` ?

Is there any chance that jobs will be missed ?

Is there any framework or design to refer?

Most of my code is in `java`, `vert.x`, `quartz` scheduler.

Comment: How many Verticles do you have deployed? When jobs are running have you checked your CPU utilization?

Comment: I am running with one verticle which runs quarts  jobs  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Quartz but to fully use your CPU by vertx you can deploy multiple Verticles. https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_specifying_number_of_verticle_instances
In official documentation they recommend verticle number = core thread * 2. I recommend to deploy core thread * 1. Best way is to experiment.